# How to change 'this' keyword color in vscode custom theme

Tags: visual-studio-code, themes

I'm working on a custom theme over the Atom One Dark Theme, but I just can't figure out how to change the 'this' keyword color. When opening Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes it shows as a variable. [with dark one theme on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvCO1.png)

But with vscode regular dark theme it does appear in a different color. [with vscode dark theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfBep.png)

Any ideas on how to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to declare a `tokenColorCustomizatons`.

```json
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "textMateRules": [
            {
                "scope" : "variable.language.this.js",
                "settings": {
                    // Include any settings you want for the this keyword.
                    "foreground": "#FF0000"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Amazing, it worked! had to do a little change but now my 'this' is on a darker blue. Thank you :)